# Show that monotonicity implies positive definiteness of the Jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

Given $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ differentiable, $x,y, p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that

> $(x-y)^T(f(x) - f(y)) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow p^TDf(x)p \geq 0, \forall p \in \mathbb{R}^n$

This is a very simple derivation, but I have trouble completing this proof.

**Proof**

($\Rightarrow$) Following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant, we write the Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $y$ as:

$$f(x) = f(y) + D_f(y)(x-y) + o(\|x-y\|)$$

Then subtracting $f(y)$ from RHS and multiplying $(x-y)^T$ on both sides yields:

$$(x-y)^T(f(x) - f(y))= (x-y)^TD_f(y)(x-y) + o(\|x-y\|^2)$$

Then LHS $ \geq 0$ implies RHS $\geq 0$

How to deal with  $o(\|x-y\|^2)?$

And is the proof correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the one-dimensional case:

$f$ is increasing iff $f' \geq 0$.

The $\Longrightarrow$-direction cannot be proven by using Taylor formular/Mean value theorem, so it is useless trying it in the general case ;) It is proven directly from the defintion of the derivative, hence we should come up with something similar:

Assume $-a := p^TDf(x)p<0$ for some $p$, w.l.o.g assume $\|p\|=1$. Choose $0<\varepsilon<a$.

By the definition of the derivative, we find some $t>0$, such that

$$\|f(x+tp)-f(x)-Df(x)tp\| < \varepsilon \|tp\|$$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $$|(tp)^T(f(x+tp)-f(x)-Df(x)tp)| \leq \|tp\| \|f(x+tp)-f(x)-Df(x)tp)\| < \varepsilon \|tp\|^2 = \varepsilon t^2$$

Have a look at the LHS:

$$|(tp)^T(f(x+tp)-f(x)-Df(x)tp)| = |(tp)^T(f(x+tp)-f(x)) - (tp)^TDf(x)tp| = |(tp)^T(f(x+tp)-f(x))+t^2a| \geq t^2a,$$

where the last inequality follows from $(tp)^T(f(x+tp)-f(x)) \geq 0$.

Hence we have $t^2a <\varepsilon t^2$, this contradicts our choice of $\varepsilon$.